# Disconnecting ArcGIS Pro from PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-pro

What is the equivalent to the ArcCatalog's `Disconnect` option in ArcGIS Pro?  I have successfully connected to a Postgresql database, but cannot figure out how to disconnect.

This is what I'm seeing on the right-click of my database connection: 
[image]

I know the ArcGIS Pro client is still connected to the postgres database:
[image]

---

I also tried:

1. Removing the connection.
2. When that didn't work, I opened a blank
   project.

Neither closed the connection.

**Update 2:**
I don't think this would matter to the connection behavior, but there's no sde/gdb in the postgresql database--just straight 9.3 postgresql database.  Thought I would mention in case others stumble upon this question.

Comment: Does it not disconnect when you close Pro?

Comment: Yes, exiting the application will close the database connections.

Comment: would say that is a bug... report it to esri support. remember pro has only just come out of beta.

Comment: Out of beta, and into prerelease.  And yes, I would say a lack of "Disconnect" is a defect.

Comment: I did report it.  Without knowing what the expected behavior **should** be, I was initially hesitant in calling that a defect. But I think its safe to say that it is one now.

Comment: There was an Esri support request logged and an enhancement was logged for this functionality to be added.

Comment: Would you be able to share details of the enhancement request, including its NIM number, please?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: `ENH-000084097 - Provide a way to disconnect database connections from ArcGIS Pro `

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @JayCummins an enhancement request appears to have been logged as:

> ENH-000084097 - Provide a way to disconnect database connections from
>   ArcGIS Pro